# The method is undefined for the Type - Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm not exactly sure how to fix this, but I'm getting undefined type errors on my multiply and divide methods in the subclass "Complex". My "Complex" class is suppose to extend my "Simple" class. The error message is as follows:

- The method multiply(int, int) is undefined for the type Simple.
- The method multiply(int, int, int) is undefined for the type Simple
- The method divide(int, int) is undefined for the type Simple.

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  class Simple {
      public int sum(int a, int b) {
          return (a + b);
      }

  public int sum(int a, int b, int c) {
      return (a + b + c);
  }

  public int remainder(int a, int b) {
      return (a - b);
  }
  ```

  }

  ```
  class Complex extends Simple {
  public int multiply(int a, int b) {
      return (a * b);
  }

  public int multiply(int a, int b, int c) {
      return (a * b * c);
  }

  public int divide(int a, int b) {
      return (a / b);
  }
  ```

  }

  ```
  class CalculatorTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Scanner, object instance
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Capture arguments, math operation
      System.out.print("Input math operation: [A]dd, [S]ubtract, [M]ultiply, [D]ivide: ");
      char mathOp = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
      System.out.print("Input 3 arguments each followed by a space: ");
      int int1 = input.nextInt();
      int int2 = input.nextInt();
      int int3 = input.nextInt();

      // Math operations selection structure
      if (mathOp == 'A' || mathOp == 'S') {
          Simple calculator = new Simple();
          if (mathOp == 'A') {
              System.out.print(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = " + calculator.sum(int1, int2) + "\n");
              System.out.print(int1 + " + " + int2 + " + " + int3 + " = " + calculator.sum(int1, int2, int3) + "\n");
          } else if (mathOp == 'S') {
              System.out.print(int1 + " - " + int2 + " = " + calculator.remainder(int1, int2) + "\n");
          }
      } else {
          Simple calculator1 = new Complex();
          if (mathOp == 'M') {
              System.out.print(int1 + " x " + int2 + " = " + calculator1.multiply(int1, int2) + "\n");
              System.out.print(int1 + " x " + int2 + " x " + int3 + " = " + calculator1.multiply(int1, int2, int3) + "\n");
          } else if (mathOp == 'D') {
              System.out.print(int1 + " / " + int2 + " = " + calculator1.divide(int1, int2) + "\n");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: The variable `calculator1`'s type is Simple. So you can't call methods on this variable if they don't exist in Simple. If you want to call methods of Complex, then type it as Complex, not Simple.